# How can non-admin users install software in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Does anyone know how can I install software on my PC without administrator permission? I know that I can change permission of some KEY in the Registry, but I don't know exactly which ones.
I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could get the app to install in `%APPDATA%` instead of `%PROGRAMFILES%`, but that would only install for the user and not the entire system.

Comment: Another option could be using portable applications

Comment: request From Admin user!!!

Answer (score 5):

As long as the software installer doesn't try to write to protected folders or registry keys,
there is usually no admin permission required. Many software installers give you the choice
of where/how to install, but some don't and if that is the case, you're pretty much out of luck. Some software doesn't even require any sort of "installation", you can just place the
executable files anywhere in your user-writable folders.

If you're not an administrator, then no, you can not change permissions on any of the protected locations.

Answer (score 0):

There is Portable apps(Includes tons of apps), 7-zip portable, globefind, resource hacker, uniExtract, and WinRar using uniextract

Comment: How would uniExtract help if user does not have admin rights ?

Answer (score -3):

if you have the folder for the program you can use it by putting it in C:Windows/System32/ and it should work this method only applies if it is blocked by group policy

Comment: The `SYSTEM32` folder cannot be changed by users without Administrator rights, so how does this work?

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? What if the program that you need to install had to affect the registry? How will that be achieved?